# pojo parse gson with invalid java names

Tags: java, android, json

i'm working with the youtube json from google-api-client :

```
{
    "apiVersion": "2.0",
    "data": {
        "updated": "2011-01-05T13:48:33.146Z",
        "totalItems": 4,
        "startIndex": 1,
        "itemsPerPage": 1,
        "items": [
            {
                "id": "YfUzMkAlOBI",
                "uploaded": "2010-12-29T16:50:47.000Z",
                "updated": "2010-12-29T16:50:47.000Z",
                "uploader": "devandroidcs",
                "category": "Entertainment",
                "title": "Teste 2",
                "description": "Description do teste2",
                "tags": [
                    "mobile"
                ],
                "thumbnail": {
                    "sqDefault": "http://i.ytimg.com/vi/YfUzMkAlOBI/default.jpg",
                    "hqDefault": "http://i.ytimg.com/vi/YfUzMkAlOBI/hqdefault.jpg"
                },
                "player": {
                    "default": "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v\u003dYfUzMkAlOBI&feature\u003dyoutube_gdata_player",
                    "mobile": "http://m.youtube.com/details?v\u003dYfUzMkAlOBI"
                }
.
.
.
}
```

at this point i should create a  field name called default at my parse java class.
Already done this parse  work with the other fields , the problem is that  , default is
a private java name  so i can't call a variable default .

how can i manage that ?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I believe your answer lies in the [JSON Field Naming Support](http://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-JSON-Field-Naming-Support):

> Gson supports some pre-defined field
>   naming policies to convert the
>   standard Java field names (i.e. camel
>   cased names starting with lower case
>   --- "sampleFieldNameInJava") to a Json field name (i.e.
>   sample_field_name_in_java or
>   SampleFieldNameInJava).

See for instance the following example:

```
private class SomeObject {
  @SerializedName("custom_naming") private final String someField;
  private final String someOtherField;

  public SomeObject(String a, String b) {
    this.someField = a;
    this.someOtherField = b;
  }
}
```

So you should be able to define the field mapping to the default value like this:

```
@SerializedName("default")
private final String someOtherNameThanDefault;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using the @Key annotation for your mapped fields, you just need to make use of a custom value that can be passed to this annotation. So choose a legal name for your field and map it as @Key("default"):

```
@Key("default")
private String defaultUrl;
```

Comment: @user569873: if the "first" solution works (I assume you mean mine, given that you said this one didn't work before you edited your comment), you should indicate that by accepting that answer, as this will help people looking for this same question in the future. There is a checked-mark to the left of every question you should use for this.

Comment: @user569873: and just a second tip to you: you should have left your first comment un-edited, so people could see why this specific suggestion didn't work for you, as one can learn something useful from that as well :)

Answer (score 2):

Just say it from my personal experience, @Key may not work on serialization/de-serialization when choosing the wrong Json parser.

(1) When you use Gson parser, like below :

```
GsonBuilder gsb = new GsonBuilder();
Gson gson = gsb.create();
OneDriveItem oneDriveItem = gson.fromJson(jasonData1, OneDriveItem.class);
```

@Key does not work, you should use @SerializedName to annotate the field name.

(2) When you use JsonFactory from the package com.google.api.client.json, like below :

```
 JacksonFactory jsonFactory=new JacksonFactory();
```

@Key should work.