# user.getInfo and GSON parsing in Java

Tags: java, api, gson, last.fm

Below is the sample response from last.fm api

```
"image": [
{
"#text": "http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/34/86765245.jpg";,
"size": "small"
},
{
"#text": "http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/64/86765245.jpg";,
"size": "medium"
},
{
"#text": "http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/126/86765245.jpg";,
"size": "large"
},
{
"#text": "http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/252/86765245.jpg";,
"size": "extralarge"
}
],
```

I am trying to parse this using GSON but don't know how to parse this line:

> "#text": "http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/126/86765245.jpg"

For instance, I use class with two fields:

```
public static final class Image {
    private String text;
    private String size;

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public String getSize() {
        return size;
    }

    public void setSize(String size) {
        this.size = size;
    }
}
```

But after the parsing I get **null** in text field because the field in json named as "#text" and not "text".

Can anybody help me please?

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4647218/pojo-parse-gson-with-invalid-java-names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [gson annotation](http://www.javacreed.com/gson-annotations-example/) @SerializedName.

```
 @SerializedName("#text")
 String text;
```