# Getting objects in a JSON response

Tags: java, json, pojo

I have a JSON response which looks like this:

```
String resp = "{"name":"Renold","age":"16"}"
```

And I have a POJO named "Person" which contains the attributes 'Name' and 'Age'. How do I extract the attributes from the JSON response and assign them to the POJO? I have already tried GSON and the object gets incorrectly assigned as "Name = name" and "Age = age" instead of the actual response.

Any other suggestions, good lads? :)

EDIT: This is what I used with GSON

```
Gson gson = new Gson(); 
final Person p= gson.fromJson(response, Person.class);
```

This left me with:

> p.Name = name;
>
> p.Age = age;

instead of p.Name = Renold.

Comment: Can u please post the code snippet which you used to parse the JSON using GSON?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you have to use `@SerializedName` to map Name to name

check this [pojo parse gson with invalid java names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4647218/pojo-parse-gson-with-invalid-java-names)

In your Pojo you have to annotate like this.

```
  @SerializedName("name")
  private final Name;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this with [Genson](http://owlike.github.io/genson/):

```
String resp = "{"name":"Renold","age":"16"}"
Genson genson = new Genson();
Person person = genson.deserialize(resp, Person.class);
```

Comment: That left me with this when debugged: "person.Name = name" and "person.Age = age". It gave me the attribute type name instead of the response attribute. This happened with GSON as well.

Comment: Can you provide the Person class. Also, in the above case you get a person object with attributes values assigned right ?? What exactly do you need...

Answer (score 0):

Please try serialization using the JObject class using org.json. e.g

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject("{\"name\":\"Renold\",\"age\":\"16"\"}");
```

Then get the properties:

```
jsonObj.get("name");
```

Comment: Hmm how do I convert my JSON response to that format you specified sir? My response is in the format of: "{"name":"Renold","age":"16"}". Sorry I'm kinda new to this :)

Comment: @Earthling The exact format in which you are going to receive the data is going to be this string : `"{\"name\":\"Renold\",\"age\":\"16"\"}"` and not `"{"name":"Renold","age":"16"}"` because if you do not escape the double quotes, then it isn't proper JSON. Try the same code with a server sending the JSON. Your code is fine. you are testing with wrong data.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using maven you can include the Jackson dependency. That will map things automagically.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the same scenario you have described and found no issues with your code except the String representation you have used. I have put my code at [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/M6uFCunJ). This sample project should resolve your issue of json format.

The string in your response should be:

```
String response = "{\"name\":\"Renold\",\"age\":16}"
```